# How to permute the numbers correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, list

My data set is a text file of 8 numbers each under this format:

```
   76768,766846646,979,3290,5244,69797,8080,3414
   7643,73467346,826382,827382,3,826,864,686
```

There is 2 special things about these numbers:

1. Each line has exactly 8 numbers seperated by a comma
2. They are all positive values.

The way i should see my data is as `x` and `y`

- x being every other value starting with the first
- y being every other value starting with the second term of each line.

so taking the first line as example `x` can be seen as `76768,979,5244,8080` and `y` as `766846646,3290,69797,3414`

What i have to do is add the highest term of `x` near the highest term of `y` and the smallest term of `x` near the smallest term of `y` so the value i should get for the first line is `76768,766846646,979,3290`

the code:

```
from functools import reduce

text = "76768,766846646,979,3290,5244,69797,8080,3414"  # input text
s = text.split(",")  # make it into a list of strings

from operator import add
output = list(
    reduce(
        add,
        zip(
            sorted(s[::2], reverse=True)[::(len(s)//2)-1],
            sorted(s[1::2], reverse=True)[::(len(s)//2)-1]
        )
    )
)
print (output)
```

the output i'm getting is however `['979', '766846646', '5244', '3290']` but i'm getting correct values occasionally with other example and not able to understand where the issue is or fix it.

Comment: so your data is (x,y) pairs on each line?

Comment: Another way to see them is x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4 assuming x2 is the highest x and x1 is the lowest x, and y1 is the highest y and y4 is the lowest y, the end result should be x2,y1,x1,y4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting strings (alphabetically), while you really need to sort the values as numbers. Start with this:

```
s = [int(i) for i in text.split(",")]  # make it into a list of numbers
```

Now the output for the example will be:

```
[76768, 766846646, 979, 3290]
```